# Disable autopopulate of select fields with database values in rails 4 edit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, edit, form-for

I'm running Rails 4.1 and I have an edit form with some values in it, I don't mind other fields on the form being autopopulated from database values, Rails does that nicely.  But I want to disable the autopopulation of one field.  Is that possible?

I'm doing the standard Rails form_for, everything works I just do not want one of the fields to autopopulate.  I do not want to set the value as blank or "" because it would overwrite the database.

Any suggestions?

edit.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @object do |f| %>
  <% f.text_field :property %>  #autopopulate from database
  <% f.text_field :property2 %> # I do not want to autopopulate.
  <% f.submit 'Submit %> 
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Clear the attribute before rendering a form.

Here's what it would look like in the view:

```
<% @object.property2.clear %>   # set attribute to an empty string
<%= form_for @object do |f| %>
  <% f.text_field :property %>  #autopopulate from database
  <% f.text_field :property2 %> # I do not want to autopopulate.
  <% f.submit 'Submit %> 
<% end %>
```

However, it is best done in the controller:

```
def edit
  # ...
  @object.property2.clear
end
```

Note that if you submit this form with a blank field, it will save a blank string in database, removing whatever was there before.

Comment: Hi Substantial, as you said, this does save the field as blank into the database which is not the intended action.  Is there a Rails callback that I can use to only save if the fields are different than what is in the database and only if it is not blank?  Seems like anyone with an Rails Edit form would need this but nothing comes up in my search for it... any pointers?  I can write my own custom method but this seems like something that should be available already.

Comment: Intentional misrepresentation of a record's state is quite uncommon and goes against Rails' conventions. You could ignore the blank parameter at update, but then clearing the attribute is impossible without some sort of secondary input ("clear attribute" checkbox) or special controller action.